# How to select one element in v.DataTable?

Tags: python, vuetify.js, jupyter

### Description

I try to create an interactive DataTable.
The idea is to open a Dialog when i click on the pencil and to fill the Dialog with the current row information. I didn't get how to obtain this information by just clicking on the pencil so I added an extra select btn to know which is the currently slected line.

Problem I don't manage to select a single line...
when I click on any of the checkbox it selects them all. Is it a bug ?

### to reproduce

```py
v.DataTable(
    v_model       = [],
    show_select   = True, 
    single_select = True,
    headers       = headers,
    items         = deserts,
    v_slots       = [
        { # the pencil for modification
            'name'    : 'item.action',
            'variable': 'item',
            'children': v.Icon(small=True, children=['mdi-pencil'])
        }
    ]
)
```

### data

```py
headers = [
    { 'text': 'Dessert (100g serving)', 'value': 'name',},
    { 'text': 'Calories'              , 'value': 'calories' },
    { 'text': 'Fat (g)'               , 'value': 'fat' },
    { 'text': 'Carbs (g)'             , 'value': 'carbs' },
    { 'text': 'Protein (g)'           , 'value': 'protein' },
    { 'text': 'Iron (%)'              , 'value': 'iron' },
    { 'text': 'Action'                , 'value': 'action'}
]

deserts = [
    {
        'name'    : 'Frozen Yogurt',
        'calories': 159,
        'fat'     : 6.0,
        'carbs'   : 24,
        'protein' : 4.0,
        'iron'    : '1%',
    },
    {
        'name'    : 'Ice cream sandwich',
        'calories': 237,
        'fat'     : 9.0,
        'carbs'   : 37,
        'protein' : 4.3,
        'iron'    : '1%',
    },
    {
        'name'    : 'Eclair',
        'calories': 262,
        'fat'     : 16.0,
        'carbs'   : 23,
        'protein' : 6.0,
        'iron'    : '7%',
    }
]
```

### Edit

If I observe the `v_model` of the `DataTable`, I realize that the values are selected according to my need it's just the display that does not match the vuetify.js behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as refered in [#106 of ipyvuetify](https://github.com/mariobuikhuizen/ipyvuetify/issues/106) 2 implementations are possible :

### widget oriented implementation

You are just forgetting the `item_key = 'name'` parameter in your `v.DataTable` :

```py
v.DataTable(
    v_model       = [],
    show_select   = True, 
    single_select = True,
    item_key      = 'name',
    headers       = headers,
    items         = deserts,
    v_slots       = [
        { # the pencil for modification
            'name'    : 'item.action',
            'variable': 'item',
            'children': v.Icon(small=True, children=['mdi-pencil'])
        }
    ]
)
```

### vuetify template version

to access the item data without the proxy of a checkbox you can use the `v.vuetifytemplate` version :

```py
import ipyvuetify as v
import traitlets

class MyDataTable(v.VuetifyTemplate):
    template = traitlets.Unicode('''
        <template>
            <div>
                <v-data-table
                    v-model="selected"
                    :show-select="true" 
                    :single-select="true"
                    :headers="headers"
                    :items="deserts"
                    item-key="name"
                >
                    <template #item.action="item">
                        <v-btn icon @click="edit_item(item.item)">
                            <v-icon>mdi-pencil<v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>

                </v-data-table>
                <v-dialog v-model="open_edit_dialog">
                    <v-card>
                        <v-card-title class="headline">
                            {{ item_to_edit.name }}
                        </v-card-title>
                        <v-card-text>
                            <v-text-field v-model="item_to_edit.calories" label="calories"/>
                        </v-card-text>    
                    </v-card>
                </v-dialog>
            </div>
        </template>
    ''').tag(sync=True)
    
    selected = traitlets.List([]).tag(sync=True)
    headers = traitlets.List([]).tag(sync=True)
    deserts = traitlets.List([]).tag(sync=True)
    
    open_edit_dialog = traitlets.Bool(False).tag(sync=True)
    item_to_edit = traitlets.Dict().tag(sync=True)
    
    def vue_edit_item(self, item):
        self.item_to_edit = item
        self.open_edit_dialog = True

my_data_table = MyDataTable(headers=headers, deserts=deserts)
my_data_table
```

Comment: In this solution it is only possible to select one element in the table. How would you modify the code to allow selecting several rows? thx